# Unable to find Percentage in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have following `SQL` code and it doesn't generate percentage value

```
    declare @prcnt numeric(5,2)=0;
    declare @nulls int=15,@total_col int=24;
    select @prcnt=(@nulls/@total_col)*100;
    select @prcnt;
```

It's fiddle can be seen [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b900942fd57522d8f9faada42bffb4d6).

Comment: Use `float`  instead of `int` ;)

Comment: @OcasoProtal can you please mention the reason as well?

Comment: don't use `float` unless you required high precision, `numeric` or `decimal` is sufficient

Comment: Because in integer division `@nulls/@total_col` is lower than 1 which will be "rounded" (floored?) to zero. And @squirell is right about precision.

Comment: Read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/precision-scale-and-length-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 If both operands are `int`, the result is `int`. At least one of operands must be `decimal`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
declare @prcnt decimal(8,4)=0;
declare @nulls decimal(8,4)=15,@total_col decimal(8,4)=24;
select @prcnt=(@nulls/@total_col)*100;
select @prcnt;
```

Answer (score 3):

The result is zero because @null and @total_col are both integers. 15 divided by 24 result is 0.625 which then converted to zero because they are integers. Use floating points or cast one of them into floating points.

```
declare @prcnt numeric(5,2)=0;
declare @nulls int=15,@total_col int=24;
select @prcnt=(cast(@nulls as numeric(19,4))/@total_col)*100;
select @prcnt;
```

Answer (score 3):

Multiplying by 1.0 or using the data type decimal would do the trick. I prefer *1.0

```
declare @prcnt numeric(5,2)=0;
declare @nulls int=15,@total_col int=24;
select @prcnt=(1.0*@nulls/@total_col)*100;
select @prcnt;
```

Answer (score 1):

try like below,here by  multipyting 1.00 engine doing the implicit cast

```
    declare @prcnt numeric(5,2)=0;
    declare @nulls int=15,@total_col int=24;
    select @prcnt=(@nulls*1.00/@total_col)*100; 
    select @prcnt;
```

or do an explicit cast

```
declare @prcnt numeric(5,2)=0;
declare @nulls int=15,@total_col int=24;
select @prcnt=(cast( @nulls as float)/@total_col)*100;
select @prcnt;
```

Answer (score 1):

@nulls and @total_col should be also numeric:

```
DECLARE @prcnt numeric(5,2)=0;
DECLARE @nulls numeric(5,2)=15, @total_col numeric(5,2)=24;
SELECT @prcnt=(@nulls/@total_col)*100 ;
SELECT @prcnt;
```

Or you can cast them while dividing:

```
DECALRE @prcnt numeric(5,2)=0;
DECLARE @nulls int=15,@total_col int=24;
SELECT @prcnt=(CAST(@nulls as numeric(5,2))/CAST(@total_col as numeric(5,2)))*100;
SELECT @prcnt;
```